# How to disallow user actions in CanCan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

In my ability.rb file, how can I set it so that only defined users can do things, else (an undefined/not logged in user) cannot do anything?

Example:

```
def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new #not logged in user
    if user.admin_user?
        can :manage, :all
    else
        #can't do anything. Cannot view, edit, or update.
    end
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've never really used CanCan, but I looked over the docs, and I don't think you need to explicitly define what the user *can't* do.

You should just be able do something like this in your controller:

```
if cannot? :destroy, @project 
  # redirect the user or do something else to disallow access
end
```

`cannot?` should return true if the user wasn't assigned a role that has any abilities defined. Conversely `can?` would return false.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a simple conditional set in your initialize function:

```
# app/models/ability.rb
def initialize(user)
  if user && user.admin_user?
    # Abilities for registered admin users
    can :manage, :all
  elsif user
    # Abilities for registered users
    can :read, :all
  else
    # Abilities for no user
  end
end
```

When `initialize` is called, `user` will likely (depending on your authentication solution) be `nil` for not logged in users, which will trigger the last branch.